# Regex: at least one of the first two character has to be a letter

Tags: regex

I am searching for a regex which cover this usecases:

- The length of the string is 8
- The first two characters "can" contain 1 digit, the rest of the 6 Charatcers are digits
- Two digits at the beginning are not allowed

**Examples:**

- `AB123456` --> good
- `1A789563` --> good
- `A2547896` --> good
- `11111111` --> BAD

I tried with:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$/
```

But this allow two digits at the beginning.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a "spelled-out" regex approach where you list all possible variations in a [grouping construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with [alternation operators](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{2})[0-9]{6}$
```

Or, if your regex engine supports lookaheads

```
^(?![0-9]{2})[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$
```

See the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RCIaxa/1) and the [second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RCIaxa/5).

The `^` asserts the position at the start of the string, then the `(?:[a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{2})` [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matches a letter + digit, digit + letter or just two letters. Then, `[0-9]{6}` matches 6 digits up to the end of the string (`$`).

The second regex matches the start of a string (`^`), then fails the match if the first two chars are digits (`(?![0-9]{2})`), then matches two alphnumeric chars (`[0-9A-Za-z]{2}`) and then six digits (`[0-9]{6}`), and asserts the position at the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: As usual, you beat me in the race :)

Comment: @WillBarnwell Sorry :)

Comment: No problem, coming up with regex answers is extra fun because I know I'm racing you or a few others, this time I still got to solve, but since my solution was the same as yours its not worth the post.

Comment: @Jonas Why unaccept? What issues have you got with this pattern?